# Why does running a macro in Visual Studio 2017 cause debugger to crash?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, macros

I have the following JavaScript macro defined in the Visual Studio 2017 IDE (using the Macros for Visual Studio extension from Microsoft DevLabs) that inserts a comment with the current date and time. I use this when editing C# code:

```
// Inserts the date and time at the cursor position.

var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getYear();

var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

// Add a zero if single digit
if (day <= 9) day = "0" + day;
if (month <= 9) month = "0" + month;
if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (hours <= 9) hours = "0" + hours;

Macro.InsertText("//");
dte.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine();
Macro.InsertText("// " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes);
dte.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine();
dte.ActiveDocument.Selection.LineUp(false, 2);
dte.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine();
Macro.InsertText(" ");
```

If I am editing C# code in VS2017 and never use this macro, when I hit F5 to debug the solution, it builds and starts up every time. If, however, I use the above macro during editing of the C# code, when I hit F5 to build and debug, it builds the solution, but when it launches, I can see in the task manager that the solution's EXE starts in suspended mode. After a few seconds, Visual Studio crashes and restarts itself.

I have used this same macro in Visual Studio 2010, 2015, and 2019 without this behavior. Visual Studio 2017 is updated to the latest build. Any clues why this is happening?

Comment: JavaScript macros in Visual Studio??  Is this using [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) or native?

Comment: Good point. I edited the question to include that the macro is implemented using the "Macros for Visual Studio" extension.